# Firewalld is not running

Tags: centos7, firewalld

When I try to add a port to FirewallsD, I get the following exception:

```
centos 7 answer FirewallD is not running
```

When I try to reload with

```
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

centos 7 answers FirewallD is not running
when I try to start with

```
sudo firewall-cmd --start
```

centos 7 answers FirewallD is not running

What can I do?

Comment: this should be posted on [su] since this has nothing to do with programming...

Answer (score 22):

**Follow the below steps** for the default installation of `firewalld` service in centos 7.

*First*: `firewalld` is pre-installed in centos 7. If `firewalld` is not installed, install it. To verify and install, issue the below commands.

```sh
rpm -qa firewalld
# expected output: firewalld-0.6.3-2.el7_7.2.noarch

# if not installed, install it
yum install firewalld
```

*Second*: `firewalld` mostly runs as a service. Check the service exists on the host.

```sh
ll /usr/lib/systemd/system | grep firewalld
# expected output: -rw-r--r-. 1 root root 674 Jan 30 2018 firewalld.service
# OR
ll /etc/systemd/system | grep firewalld
```

*Third*: Verify firewalld service is running and enabled.

> If the service is running and it's not enabled, every restart will bring it down. Use the below command.

```sh
# check the status of the service (running and enabled)
systemctl status firewalld

# if the service is not running, start it
systemctl start firewalld

# if the service has exited, restart it(check for error if any)
systemctl restart firewalld

# if the service is not enabled, enable it
systemctl enable firewalld
```

Answer (score 15):

first check status of `firewalld` status by below command :

```
sudo systemctl status firewalld
```

if you get output `Active: active` so run the following command :

```
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
```

**but** if you get output `Active: inactive (dead)` or `Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)` follow the below commands :

```
sudo systemctl unmask --now firewalld
```

the output should indicate that the `symlink has been removed`.
then run the below command :

```
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
```

after enabling the firewall, start the `firewalld` service:

```
sudo systemctl start firewalld
```

when the system executes the command, there is no output. Therefore, it is wise to verify whether the firewall has been activated successfully.

check firewall status with:

```
sudo systemctl status firewalld
```

if you see the `Active: active (running)` message you can now do what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

First install and start firewalld service

```
sudo yum install -y firewalld
sudo systemctl start firewalld
```

Then start adding your rules with *firewall-cmd* command. Use *--permanent* flag to keep changes after system reboot.

You may have to open ssh service if using remote SSH access.

Then finally update firewalld with the new configuration

```
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```